# How can I replace the default favicon in an slc loopback generated express webapp?

Tags: express, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have generated an app using slc loopback command.  So the generated express webapp has its strongloop favicon.  How can I change the favicon?  There is no documentation on how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loopback favicon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412591/loopback-favicon)

Answer (score 2):

Update middleware.json as follows:

Rout to static files, where .ico file is, for example if you have a client folder in project and the file name is favicon.ico.

```
"files": {
    "loopback#static": {
      "params": "$!../client"
    }
 }
```

In same file add parmas to middleware favicon

```
"initial:before": {
       "loopback#favicon": {
          "params": "$!../client/favicon.ico"
       }
    }
```

Finally, if you are working in HTML5 add to head node

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

In Chrome a 32x32 image works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your server/middleware.json

```
"initial:before": {
    "loopback#favicon": {
      "params": "path-to-your/favicon.ico"
    }
  }
  ......
```

Answer (score -1):

I have replaced the favicon.ico in myproject\node_modules\loopback with another 16x16 favion.ico.

It works but not as clean as the above solution i guess.

Comment: the solution will work. Are u getting any error ? and also please add comment on my answer so that i will get notification regarding the same instead of adding your comment as a answer

Comment: This is working in local. But as we dont push our own node modules with other so it will show same old favicon for them.